# How to stop handler that is inside onCreate using onBackPressed outside onCreate?

Tags: java, android

I am calling Runnable inside onCreate using handler and want to stop it by using onBackPressed outside the onCreate. How to stop Runnable function outside the onCreate?

I have try to rewrite Runnable outside the onCreate but it's not working.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
define Runnable and start Runnable
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
stop Runnable
}
```

I expect onBackPressed can stop Runnable outside the onCreate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stop any of runnable by removing the callbacks, Use

```
handler.removeCallbacks(runnableRunner);
```

If you want to remove all active callbacks, Use

```
handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

Comment: If I put handler.removeCallbacks(my_runnable); in onBackPressed outside onCreate. I should redefine the Runnable outside onCreate

Comment: just define your runnable variable at class level and use it.

Comment: or you can use `handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);` it will remove all active callbacks

Comment: "removeCallback()" and similar methods works by removing the Runnable from Handler's queue, but if the Runnable is already running those methods WON'T work.

Answer (score 1):

Running a Runnable that takes more than few milliseconds on the MainThread is WRONG because it freezes the interface. If your Runnable runs in a different Thread, than you have just to send a "mThread.interrupt()" command to that specific Thread to terminate it. If you don't want to terminate the other Thread, than you have to implement Messages in that Thread and then send a specific Message to its Handler.

Comment: This is the only correct answer. The other ones would only work if the handler has not started executing the runnable.

Answer (score 0):

**You can stop Runnable by calling:-**

mHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable);